# Additional Section appear by hover in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the pricing tables developed via Bootstrap:

http://www.bootply.com/VyHsJBDoNc

How can I do so the hover on a span (+ More Information!) makes an extra information appear like on the screenshot attached.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: You can use Bootstrap's [Popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers).

Comment: qtip2 is alos a useful jquery plugin http://qtip2.com/ It has bootstrap support as well

Comment: what kind of client side script framework would you like to use (Angular2, Jquery, etc..)?

Comment: @DánielKis, jQuery will be perfect

Comment: @MuhammadUsman unfortunately, popover works by click, not by hover

Comment: @Morgari Default event is `click`. You can customize this to `hover`.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/sDIeae9Fye

Comment: Try tool tip for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution

```css
body
{
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.panel
{
    text-align: center;
}
.panel:hover { box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 1px 5px rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.35); }
.panel-body
{
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.the-price
{
    background-color: rgba(220,220,220,.17);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #dcdcdc, inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}
span.glyphicon-preload {
    color: #23b070;
    padding-right: 7px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.table {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.table>tbody>tr>td {
    padding: 14px;
}
.btn-insta {
    margin-top: 13px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.the-price h1
{
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 42px;
    color: #333;
}
.panel-title {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;  
}
.subscript
{
    font-size: 25px;
}
.table-premium p {
    font-weight: 700;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
.table-free p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
span.mini {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #31708f;
}
.info {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 40px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 5%;
  background: #5cb85c !important;
  padding: 10px;
}
.panel-footer:hover .info {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        Basic Plan</h3>
   
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="the-price">
                        <h1>FREE</h1>
                        <span class="mini">Runs for 12 Hours
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-success" role="button">Activate</a>    
                    </span></div>
                    <table class="table table-free">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td>
                               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>Option 1</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="active">
                            <td>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>Option 2</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>Option 3</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="active">
                            <td>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>Option 4</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>Option 5</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="active">
                            <td>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>Option 6</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>Option 7</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                   <span class="more"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> More information!</span>
                <div class="info well">
                   <span> More information! More information! More information! More information! More information! More information! More information! More information! More information! More information! More information! More information! More information! More information! More information! More information!</span>
              </div>

              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Great Solution, @Banzay! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

CSS:-

```
body
{
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.panel
{
    text-align: center;
}
.panel:hover { box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 1px 5px rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.35); }
.panel-body
{
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.the-price
{
    background-color: rgba(220,220,220,.17);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #dcdcdc, inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}
span.glyphicon-preload {
    color: #23b070;
    padding-right: 7px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.table {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.table>tbody>tr>td {
    padding: 14px;
}
.btn-insta {
    margin-top: 13px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.the-price h1
{
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 42px;
    color: #333;
}
.panel-title {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;  
}
.subscript
{
    font-size: 25px;
}
.table-premium p {
    font-weight: 700;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
.table-free p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
span.mini {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #31708f;
}

.moreinfo{
position: absolute;
    top: -37px;
    background: #23b070;
    padding: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
.panel-footer{
position:relative;
}

.moreinfo:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #23b070;
    bottom: -10px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;

    }
```

HTML as follow

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
   <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">Basic Plan</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
         <div class="the-price">
            <h1>FREE</h1>
            <span class="mini">Runs for 12 Hours
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-success" role="button">Activate</a>    
             </span>
         </div>
         <table class="table table-free">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>Option 1</p>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="active">
                   <td>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>Option 2</p>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>Option 3</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                   <td>
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>Option 4</p>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>Option 5</p>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                  <td>
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>Option 6</p>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td>
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>Option 7</p>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-footer">
             <div class="moreinfo" style"display:none;">hi</div>
               <span class="more"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> More information!</span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript :-

```
$('.more').mouseover(function(){
   $('.moreinfo').show()
})

$('.more').mouseleave(function(){
   $('.moreinfo').hide()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of possible solutions.
If you want to use Bootstrap components, you could go for [popover component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers).

Otherwise, You could just use some jQuery event handlers and functions?

```
$(".more").hover(
  // On Hover
  function() {
    // Show the information div
    // $("#moreInfo").show();
  }, 
  // On Leave
  function() {
    // Hide the information div
    // $("#moreInfo").hide();
  }
);
```